# Replacing part of string with a HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I'm using plain Javascript to replace part of a string with an HTML Element.

I'm using the following script to do what I need, consider `var data` to be an array of objects where `data[objectAtIndex].text` has the following example string `{0} is the right answer`, but it can also contain `Something {0} fishy`. The `{0}` part of the string can change place at any time.

```
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div");
textDiv.innerHTML = data[i].text.replace(pattern, select);
```

The regular expression I use looks like `var pattern = /\{0\}/i;`

Now, this halfway works, only it converts the select element to string, which yields `[object HTMLSelectElement]` instead of the actual element itself.

I want the actual element, and not the string representation of this, and I can't really find any answers which doesn't utilize jQuery.

Comment: Your wording is confusing. You say, "I want the actual element, and not the string representation of this", but you must set innerHtml to a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution. Use `select.outerHTML`

```
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div");
textDiv.innerHTML = data[i].text.replace(pattern, select.outerHTML);
```

and widely [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility).

Live example:

```js
var text = "This is a <strong>test</strong> {0} Testing <em>1 2 3</em>"

var pattern = /\{0\}/i;

var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div");

textDiv.innerHTML = text
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);

setTimeout(function(){
    textDiv.innerHTML = text.replace(pattern, select.outerHTML);
}, 1000)
```

Comment: Seems really roundabout to create an element just to get the markup for it.

Comment: You make the assumption that all the OP wants is the element tag name. Maybe they will want more. This method allows them to use DOM methods on the select node before converting it to text.

Comment: No, I make the assumption that writing the markup for the element is entirely feasible. Or if not, then one should append the element created rather than make a trip through markup and parsing.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your element(s) in a temp `<div>` and then get its `.innerHTML`.

```
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    tempDiv = document.createElement("div");

tempDiv.appendChild(select);
textDiv.innerHTML = data[i].text.replace(pattern, tempDiv.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Seems really roundabout to create an element just to get the markup for it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I guess you could use `.outerHTML`, but I thought that wasn't supported in all browsers.

Comment: That would still be creating an element just to get markup for it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: That's true.  I wasn't sure of the rest of his code (I assumed this was just an example), I guess you could just make the HTML as a string to start with.

Comment: Hey guys. I'm appending additional options to the select in an inner for loop. The data array is looped through, then I create the options in an inner loop, which is then appended to the select after it's done.

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen, this is why my answer is relevant. Do whatever you want to the element, and just call element.outerHtml

Comment: @RocketHazmat it's [standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen: You can do that directly with markup, too. But in any case, you have several options in the various answers here, including directly using that element you've built up with your loop (*without* converting it back to markup).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Definitely a lot to take note of here, thank you for your detailed explanation! I tagged cdosbom's question as answer because he made it work with the minimal amount of code, this is just a small school assignment. I've added your answer to my little journal though, thank you so much!

Comment: @NichlasTorgersen: Yes, that's definitely the *shortest*. :-) Note that it was wrong (I just noticed), the property is `outerHTML`, not `outerHtml`. I've fixed his answer.

Answer (score 2):

By using `innerHTML`, you're using markup. So one option is, just use markup (but more options follow):

```
var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
textDiv.innerHTML = data[i].text.replace(pattern, "<select></select>");
```

Live example:

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    text: "This is a <strong>test</strong> {0} Testing <em>1 2 3</em>"
  }
};
var i = 0;
var pattern = /\{0\}/i;
var textDiv = document.createElement("div");
textDiv.innerHTML = data[i].text.replace(pattern, "<select></select>");
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);
```

If you *don't* want to use markup, you can append the part of the string before the `{0}`, then the element, then the part of the string after the `{0}`:

```
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    text = data[i].text,
    index = text.indexOf("{0}"); // No need for case-insensitivity
if (index === -1) {
    index = text.length;
}
textDiv.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index);
textDiv.appendChild(select);
if (index < text.length) {
    textDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text.substring(index + 3));
}
```

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    text: "This is a <strong>test</strong> {0} Testing <em>1 2 3</em>"
  }
};
var i = 0;
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    text = data[i].text,
    index = text.indexOf("{0}"); // No need for case-insensitivity
if (index === -1) {
    index = text.length;
}
textDiv.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index);
textDiv.appendChild(select);
if (index < text.length) {
    textDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text.substring(index + 3));
}
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);
```

Or if the pattern *has* to be a regex:

```
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    text = data[i].text,
    match = pattern.exec(text),
    index = match ? match.index : text.length;
textDiv.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index);
textDiv.appendChild(select);
if (match) {
    textDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text.substring(index + match[0].length));
}
```

```js
var data = {
  0: {
    text: "This is a <strong>test</strong> {0} Testing <em>1 2 3</em>"
  }
};
var i = 0;
var pattern = /\{0\}/i;
var select = document.createElement("select"),
    textDiv = document.createElement("div"),
    text = data[i].text,
    match = pattern.exec(text),
    index = match ? match.index : text.length;
textDiv.innerHTML = text.substring(0, index);
textDiv.appendChild(select);
if (match) {
    textDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", text.substring(index + match[0].length));
}
document.body.appendChild(textDiv);
```